# Compare $20^{21}$ and $21^{20}$ using Newton Binomial Expansion.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Compare $20^{21}$ and $21^{20}$ using Newton Binomial Expansion. I mean compare them using $(a+b)^n$ . I think writing 21 = 20 +1 may help but i can't get to an answer.

Comment: What did you get when you worked out $(20 + 1)^{20}$?

Comment: @Magdiragdag Hi. First, I Think I can use it but after a writing a few term of it, I think calculating the number is easier than working with this.

Comment: Try again, and compare each of the terms with $20^{20}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{21^{20}}{20^{20}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{20}\right)^{20} = \sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{20}{k}\frac{1}{20^k}<\sum_{k=0}^{20}\frac{1}{k!}<1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{18}{2}<12 $$
hence $21^{20} \color{red}{<} 20\cdot 20^{20} = 20^{21}$.

---

This is more or less the same argument leading to
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}.$$

Comment: how did you find $<\sum_{k=0}^{20}\frac{1}{k!}<1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{18}{2} $

Comment: @titansarus: $$\binom{20}{k}=\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot\ldots}{k(k-1)\cdots}<\frac{20^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: Then the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{20}\frac{1}{k!}$ has $21$ terms. The first three are $1,1,\frac{1}{2}$, the remaining $18$ are less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Isn't C(20,k) = 20! / (k! (20-k)!) ? I think what you wrote is 20! / k!, isn't it?

Comment: @titansarus: ok, let we state it clearly: $$\binom{20}{k}=\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot\ldots\cdot (21-k)}{k!}<\frac{20^k}{k!}.$$